# TCP server with user accounts, connection threading, and groups/permissions

Tags: python, beginner, multithreading, python-3.x, socket

This is a TCP server I am currently working on. It is accessed through telnet (I know it isn't secure, its just a project for uni). The server is programmed in Python 3.

I am currently trying to figure out how to implement thread locking in my program, how to create user sessions, and the best way to implement a set of commands with authorization and group checking. Each user is assigned a group (either member or admin). I want to be able to put the commands in a dictionary or class (not sure which would be best). I also don't know how I will remove the connection thread from the dictionary when the person leaves. I am open to all constructive criticism. Tell me what I can improve on. I am very new to coding (couple months in Python and C).

To test the server yourself, run the Python script and telnet into your internal IP address.

```
# TCP Server for user database

# Import modules
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
import socket

# Global variables
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # Host
port = 23                                         # Port
addr = (host, port)                               # Tuple address
form_addr = host + ":" + str(port)                # Formatted Address
buff = 2048                                       # Buffer rate

connections = {}
users = {}

# Function to validate forms - Have not used it yet
def validate(form_names, forms, min_len=0, max_len=250):
    for form in forms and form_name in form_names:
        if form >= min_len and form <= max_len:
            if form_name == "username":
                return form in users
            return True
        return False

# User class to store individual data for users
class User():
    def __init__(self, password, group, join_date):
        self.password = password
        self.group = group
        self.join_date = join_date


# Threaded connections - Gives each connection its own thread
class Connection(Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, conn_addr):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = conn                     # Connection object
        self.conn_addr = conn_addr           # Connection address (string)

    def send(self, message):                 # Sends data to the client
        try:
            self.conn.send(message.encode())
        except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
            print(str(e))

    def recieve(self, form_name=""):         # Recieves data from the client
        self.send(form_name + " -> ")
        try:
            return self.conn.recv(buff).decode()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            self.send("Type exit exit")

    def register(self):
        username = self.recieve(form_name="New Username")
        password = self.recieve(form_name="New Password")

        # Assign new user to object
        users[username] = \
        User(password, "Member", 
             datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

    def login(self):
        username = self.recieve(form_name="Username")
        password = self.recieve(form_name="Password")

        # Perform check
        if username in users:
            if users[username].password == password:
                self.send("Successful login")  # Haven't figured out what to do here yet

    def run(self):
        self.send("Welcome to the server\n")   # Runs when the thread initializes
        while True:
            command = self.recieve().split()
            if not command:  # Checks for user connection loss
                break

# Create socket instance
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind to local ip/port
print("\nStarting server on " + form_addr)
try:
    sock.bind(addr)
except socket.error as e:  # Check for port binding error
    print(str(e))

# Listen and accept incoming connections
sock.listen(3)

def listener():
    conn, conn_addr = sock.accept()     # Waits for incoming connection
    conn_addr = conn_addr[0] + ":" + \
                str(conn_addr[1])

    print("Connection from client: " + conn_addr + "\n")

    connections[conn_addr] = Connection(conn, conn_addr) # Initiates connection thread
    connections[conn_addr].start() # Starts run sequence
    # After here the listener goes back to wait for multiple connections

Thread(target=listener).start()

while True:
    command = input("Server command: ")  # Nothing here yet, work in progress
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your `validate` function. First, you have a comment that would be a docstring if it contained useful infromation. It's already clear its' a function that validates, and since it takes the parameters `form_names` and `forms` we can guess what it validates. Why not explain *what* it validates. Then put it as a docstring

```
def validate(form_names, forms, min_len=0, max_len=250):
    """Validates if forms are correctly fooed and bared"""

    for form in forms and form_name in form_names:
        if form >= min_len and form <= max_len:
            if form_name == "username":
                return form in users
            return True
        return False
```

I didn't even know `for form in forms and form_name in form_names` was valid syntax. It doesn't work in Python 2.7, but perhaps it's in 3.x. Either way, it's less readable than using the `zip` function.

```
    for form, form_name in zip(forms, form_names):
```

`zip` just creates a list of tuples from each element of both lists. It will give values to both `form` and `form_name` simultaneously.

Also you can compress the `form` length check into one comparison because Python allows multiple operators in one expression:

```
        if min_len <= form <= max_len:
```

However, even still one thing confuses me here. In **Every** outcome you're returning a value on the first iteration. I'm unsure if you didn't realise that or you misunderstand `return` values. `return` will always end the function instantly, meaning you wont iterate over any of the other values in `forms` and `form_names`. This makes the `for` loop redundant as you could just check the first element of the list, but I presume this isn't what you want.

I suspect what you want is to `return False` if any of the forms don't fit the length parameters or if the username doesn't exist in users. In this case, you don't want to `return True` until the whole `for` loop has run without catching a condition that returns `False`.

If that assumption is correct, here's how I could write this:

```
def validate(form_names, forms, min_len=0, max_len=250):
    """Validates forms are valid lengths and username exists"""

    for form, form_names in zip(forms, form_names):
        if not min_len <= form <= max_len:
            return False
            if form_name == "username" and form not in users:
                return False
    return True
```

As you can see, we're now focused on checking for the `False` conditions, and if we leave the loop without coming across any invalidating conditions we know we can just `return True`.